# Iphone Open With in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

is it possible to show a PDF in a UIWebView with the option Open in Books and Open With at the top of the WebView? I don't know how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `UIDocumentInteractionController` on top of the web view, it will allow the user to open the pdf in iBooks.

Comment: Thanks, i found this code http://andycodes.tumblr.com/post/738375724/ios4-sdk-opening-pdfs-in-ibooks but i don't know how can i put in on top of the view.
Besides, i need to have download the file, don't I?
Thanks

Comment: No, you don't have to download the pdf first. About presenting it, the class itself is not a view, but you can let it draw a view via presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:. Everything is already pretty much described in your posted sample code.

Answer (score 0):

NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathforResource:@"ResourceName" ofType:@"pdf"] ;
 or path can be any http url too.

NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

UIWebView * webView = ....;

[webView loadRequest:request];

This should show the pdf in webview. But seems you are asking to open the pdf in some other app, which part I didn't understand completely. Can you explain?